# Como remover um mapeamento no visual studio no tfs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, team-foundation-server

Como eu faço para remover um mapeamento feito pelo VS 2010 Ultimate no tfs? Preciso fazer isso, para mapear corretamente, pois está errado.

Comment: Existem formas de fazer isso pelo Visual Studio. porém eu só conheço a forma bruta, que é abrir o arquivo *.sln* da solução no bloco de notas e tirar a seção do TFS manualmente.

Comment: Eu fiz assim. Peguei o servidor do tfs e cliquei com o direito e me apareceu no popup menu dele a opção Remove Map. Fiz isso e funcionou.

Comment: Posta isso como resposta :)

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz assim. Peguei o servidor do tfs e cliquei com o direito e me apareceu no popup menu dele a opção Remove Map. Fiz isso e funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer isto, existem algumas opções:

- No Source Control Explorer, acesse o Dropdown de Workspaces;
- Nele, selecione "Workspaces...". Você verá uma jenala para gestão dos seus workspaces e mapeamentos;
- Selecione o Workspace que deseja editar (que contenha o mapeamento da sua pasta) e clique em "Edit..."
- Aqui, nesta janela, você consegue tanto remover o mapeamento quanto ajustado. Isto é importante porque vi que você quer mapear corretamente, não é?

Abraços,